# build array of object from tree object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, tree

I'm trying to get into javascript's built-in `reduce` function and with the help of that build objects inside array.
But you can use whatever function or method you want.

**Expected output**

```
[
  { 'team1': [14697807552, 6858384], '2021': [14697807552, 6858384], 'pepsi': [null, null], 'cola': [14697807552, 6858384] },
  { 'team2': [10268029152, 6922128], '2021': [10268029152, 6922128], 'pepsi': [null, 4800], 'cola': [10268029152, 6917328] },
]
```

**What I tried to do**

I created a function which takes array as an argument and calls reduce for each array's element.

```js
function transform(arr, obj = {}) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const newObj = {};
    newObj[item.name] = item.metrics;
    acc.push(newObj);

    if (item.children) {
      transform(item.children, newObj);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}
console.log(transform(arr))
```

```html
<script>
  const arr = [{
      "name": "team1",
      "metrics": [
        14697807552,
        6858384
      ],
      "children": [{
        "name": "2021",
        "metrics": [
          14697807552,
          6858384
        ],
        "children": [{
            "name": "pepsi",
            "metrics": [
              null,
              null
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "cola",
            "metrics": [
              14697807552,
              6858384
            ]
          }
        ]
      }]
    },
    {
      "name": "team2",
      "metrics": [
        10268029152,
        6922128
      ],
      "children": [{
        "name": "2021",
        "metrics": [
          10268029152,
          6922128
        ],
        "children": [{
            "name": "pepsi",
            "metrics": [
              null,
              4800
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "cola",
            "metrics": [
              10268029152,
              6917328
            ]
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  ]
</script>
```

But it gives me output that I don't want:

```
[
  { team1: [ 14697807552, 6858384 ] },
  { team2: [ 10268029152, 6922128 ] }
]
```

If you didn't understand my question or you have question, ask me. Thanks for paying attention!

Comment: what if you have more than one year inside?

Comment: @NinaScholz for example, if there are more years inside `team1`, it should be like: { 'team1': [14697807552, 6858384], '2021': [...], '2020': [...] etc}

Comment: what happens with the children of the years?

Comment: @NinaScholz is it possible to have same property names inside an object? if not you can ignore year's children and return an object like this `{ team1: [...],  2021: [...], 2022: [...] }`

Comment: Please note that a key like '2021' as an *index*, and so it will always be ordered *before* other properties in the object.

Comment: please add an example with more than one year and children and the wanted result of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform` function doesn't do anything with the second argument `obj`, and so when you call `transform` recursively, `newObj` is not extended: this makes the recursive call losing any desired effect.

Instead of passing that second argument, you could use `Object.assign` to *collect* all objects that come back from recursion, and so merge them into one object:

```js
const convert = arr =>
    arr?.map(({name, metrics, children}) => 
        Object.assign({[name]: metrics}, ...convert(children))) ?? [];

const arr = [{"name": "team1","metrics": [14697807552,6858384],"children": [{"name": "2021","metrics": [14697807552,6858384],"children": [{"name": "pepsi","metrics": [null,null]},{"name": "cola","metrics": [14697807552,6858384]}]}]},{"name": "team2","metrics": [10268029152,6922128],"children": [{"name": "2021","metrics": [10268029152,6922128],"children": [{"name": "pepsi","metrics": [null,4800]},{"name": "cola","metrics": [10268029152,6917328]}]}]}];

console.log(convert(arr));
```

Please realise that a property like '2021' is an *index* and will be ordered before other, non-index properties. Even if you print an object like `{ 'a': 2, '2021': 1 }` you'll get the keys in opposite order for that same reason.

If the *order* of the object keys is important to you, then you should go for an array of pairs in stead of a plain object. Arrays are the structure of choice when you need order, and plain objects should be used when order is not essential.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about property order for index tbh

Answer (score 0):

I have found a bit different solution:)
It is longer than answer from @trincot but also works

```js
const arr = [{"name": "team1","metrics": [14697807552,6858384],"children": [{"name": "2021","metrics": [14697807552,6858384],"children": [{"name": "pepsi","metrics": [null,null]},{"name": "cola","metrics": [14697807552,6858384]}]}]},{"name": "team2","metrics": [10268029152,6922128],"children": [{"name": "2021","metrics": [10268029152,6922128],"children": [{"name": "pepsi","metrics": [null,4800]},{"name": "cola","metrics": [10268029152,6917328]}]}]}];

const handleArr = (list, rez) => {
  list.forEach((item) => {
    rez[item.name] = item.metrics;
    item.children && handleArr(item.children, rez);
  });
};

const handle = (list) => {
  const rezArr = [];
  for (const item of list) {
    const rezObj = { [item.name]: item.metrics };
    item.children && handleArr(item.children, rezObj);
    rezArr.push(rezObj);
  }
  return rezArr;
};

console.log(handle(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

This approahc returns a different result and uses all previous information to get a [denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) of the data.

```js
const
    flat = array => array.flatMap(({ name, metrics, children }) => children
        ? flat(children).map(q => ({ [name]: metrics, ...q }))
        : { [name]: metrics }),
    data = [{ name: "team1", metrics: [14697807552, 6858384], children: [{ name: "2021", metrics: [14697807552, 6858384], children: [{ name: "pepsi", metrics: [null, null] }, { name: "cola", metrics: [14697807552, 6858384] }] }] }, { name: "team2", metrics: [10268029152, 6922128], children: [{ name: "2021", metrics: [10268029152, 6922128], children: [{ name: "pepsi", metrics: [null, 4800] }, { name: "cola", metrics: [10268029152, 6917328] }] }] }],
    result = flat(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```